# Error using ¥usepackage{pdfpages}

Tags: pdfpages

When ¥usepackage{pdfpages} is added in a tex document, the error is occurred as follows.
Let me know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Proably you want `\usepackage{pdfpages}`? That is not the same as `¥usepackage{pdfpages}`!

Comment: It's anybody's guess here. You have some character that wants to be set, but forms part of the preamble. The problem seems to follow immediately after `\usepackage{xcolor}`.

Comment: `<cheek>` as a professional LaTeX detective, I don't think that's the issue.  `</cheek>` It's choking on `\input{pp\AM@driver.def}` – what is this file and does it inadvertently output any text?  It's anybody's guess with a question that gives no MWE, though.

Comment: @SeanAllred I didn't say it would solve the problem. I thought it might marginally improve the question. Using `¥usepackage{pdfpages}` would be expected to result in a similar error but it is clearly not the culprit here since the package is loaded successfully earlier. However, there is something odd about it since it appears to be loaded from the working directory. But, as you say...

Comment: @cfr …there's no way to know ;)

Comment: @cfr -- this person is using `ptex` -- the japanese-adapted software.  this uses the yen symbol instead of a backslash as the escape character.  see the last page of [this tugboat excerpt](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23gendel.pdf).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. I didn't know that. But why does it use the backslash in the output in that case?

Comment: @cfr -- not sure, but a lot of values are hard-coded in the internal tex tables, and the visible character associated with `\catcode0` might be among those.  that's the backslash.